# iStat Menus: World clock out of sync

Tags: mac

[Self-answering for posterity.]

My iStat Menus 3 world clocks are behind the system time. What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

**[Update: This seems to be fixed in version 5 of iStat Menus.]**

This seems to be a bug in iStat Menus. The last working version is 3.23. Here is the download link:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/bjango/files/istatmenus3/istatmenus3.23.zip

Downgrading to 3.23 (and disabling "check for updates") solved the problem for me.

Note that downgrading will reset all your settings, so you'll have to configure everything anew.

Comment: This seems to be fixed in version 5 of iStat Menus.